# Hatcher Theorem 1B.8 / Proposition 1B.9 concluding that a map inducing the identity is homotopic to the identity?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces, cw-complexes

In introducing the concept of $K(G, 1)$, Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*  proves the theorem that the homotopy type of a CW complex $K(G, 1)$ is uniquely determined
by $G$, by citing a proposition and claiming the proposition may be used to deduce the theorem. I am wondering why the bolded statement is true here:

> **Proposition 1B.9.** Let $X$ be a connected CW complex and let $Y$ be a $K(G, 1)$. Then every homomorphism $\pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is induced by a map $(X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ that is unique up to homotopy fixing $x_0$.
>
> To deduce the theorem from this, let $X$ and $Y$ be CW complex $K(G, 1)$’s with isomorphic fundamental groups. The proposition gives maps $f : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ and $g : (Y, y0) \to (X, x0)$ inducing inverse isomorphisms $\pi_1(X, x_0) \cong \pi_1(Y, y_0)$. Then $fg$ and $gf$ induce the identity on $\pi_1$ **and hence are homotopic to the identity maps**.

I am aware that in general, a map inducing the identity on $\pi_1$ is not necessarily homotopic to the identity, so why in this context can this argument be made? I am specifically looking for a justification that one would be able to follow at this point in Hatcher's text.

Comment: This has been asked before but annoyingly has no answer relevant to your question. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/948723/815585) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124713/815585)

Comment: Well, observe in the very first paragraph that Hatcher claims homomorphisms on $\pi_1$ are in bijection with based homotopy classes of map $(X,x_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ (in our very specific case of $K(G,1)$ spaces!). This would give you what you want. It therefore suffices to verify Hatcher's first claim... which he probably does do in the next few sentences

Comment: eric wolfsey's answer is the correct one, but one perspective to take is via whitehead's theorem. Both the proof of 1b.9 and whiteheads theorem can be proven basically by inducting up skeleta. The proof of 1b.9 is an early example of obstruction theory (but just done sort of ad hoc iirc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This last claim is another application of Proposition 1B.9.  By the proposition, there is a *unique* (up to homotopy) map $(X,x_0)\to (X,x_0)$ that induces the identity on $\pi_1$.  One such map is the identity map, and another such map is $gf$, so they must be homotopic.  Similarly $fg$ must be homotopic to the identity $(Y,y_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ since there is a unique (up to homotopy) such map that induces the identity on $\pi_1$.